# ExpandableListView adds +1 Item extra per empty childItem

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist, expandablelistview

Ive run into a little bit of a logical problem, and I cant understand how to fix it.

I have an ArrayList and out of this ArrayList I want to load objects into an ExpListView by reading the parameter Day, which is set by get().getDay() from the custom ArrayList.

This works, however, when the list is empty or more than one childItem in the Expandable Listview, they duplicate beyond my understanding.

The list loads items like this:

**createrecipeCollection()**

```
private void createRecipeCollection(){

for (int i = 0; i < rData.size(); i++) {

String weekday = rData.get(i).getDay();

    if (weekday.equals("Monday")) {
         loadChild(rData);
    }
    else if (weekday.equals("Tuesday"))
         loadChild(rData);
    else if (weekday.equals("Wednesday"))
         loadChild(rData);
    else if (weekday.equals("Thursday"))
         loadChild(rData);
    else if (weekday.equals("Friday"))
         loadChild(rData);
    else if (weekday.equals("Saturday"))
          loadChild(rData);
    else if (weekday.equals("Sunday"))
          loadChild(rData);
    else
         loadChild(Empty); 

recipeCollection.put(weekday, childList);
}
}
```

**loadchild**

```
private void loadChild(ArrayList<ObjectFinder> rData) {
 for (ObjectFinder comparer : rData)
     childList.add(comparer);
}
```

The result is something like this:

[image: Image of Bug here]

As you can see, there is a whole bunch of empty-child (Ive labeled them in the adapter as "asd") items under the GroupItem, I dont know how they got there - and they seem to expand with +1 per groupitem that is empty or causes an NPE.

Thankful for any help I can get

Comment: if you look at child list in the debugger what do you see? are there extra empty childs? or are they created by the adapter? also the implementation of your adapter might be helpful.

Comment: I added the Adapter. Its not giving me anything logical in the debugger (of what I can see). I think there is something wrong with the createRecipeCollection() - But I cannot for the life of my figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok here's the fix

```
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    List<ObjectFinder> group = rCollection.get(weekData.get(groupPosition));
    if (group == null) return 0;
    return group.size();
}
```

the issue you're getting is because before you would catch a null pointer exception when `rCollection.get(weekData.get(groupPosition))` which returns null because there is no entries in that group, and if there was a null pointer exception you would return the groupPosition as the number of children, so the first group (index 0) has no children, the second group (index 1) has 1 child, etc.

the code above will fix the problem, however I'd remove many of those try catches you have in your adapter (as those are where you're going to see the most bugs, handle null cases don't just ignore them!!). I'd also look at defaulting group lists to empty rather then null that will fix the issue above as `rCollection` will have a valid entire for every group.

Comment: Wow, tanks Eluvatar. Im going to try it once I get home.

Comment: Again, thanks you a billion. Wish I could upvote you a thousand times more. I hear what youre saying, that its better to handle null exceptions then trying to ignore them. I learned a lot, again. Thank you!